# Get the SelectedItem of DataGridViewComboBoxCell VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

Very good afternoon to all,
The problem I have now is that I can not get the value selected as a combobox, I'm trying to set the text and value to each item in the combobox of each cell in the datagrid.
My Code:

CLASS MyListItem:

```
Public Class MyListItem
    Private mText As String
    Private mValue As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal pText As String, ByVal pValue As String)
        mText = pText
        mValue = pValue
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return mText
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As String
        Get
            Return mValue
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return mText
    End Function
End Class
```

Form Load:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
Dim dgvcbc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
dgvcbc.Items.Add(New MyListItem("Text to be displayed", "value of the item"))
```

Try to Display Selected value:

```
Dim oItem As MyListItem = CType(**dgvcbc.SelectedItem**, MyListItem)
MessageBox.Show("The Value of the Item selected is: " & oItem.Value)
```

**ERROR:** 'SelectedItem' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell'

If anyone has any idea how to set the values ​​and text to each item of each cell with combobox, I'd be very grateful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Value` property according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx):

> Unlike the ComboBox control, the DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not
>   have SelectedIndex and SelectedValue properties. Instead, selecting a
>   value from a drop-down list sets the cell Value property.

To load the DataGridViewComboBoxCell you need to set the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.datasource.aspx).

Depending on the type of data in the datasource, you may also need to set the DisplayMember to choose the property or column name to show in the display portion of the control and the ValueMember to choose the property or column name that is used to set the Value property of the control when an item is selected.

Here is some additional guidance from MSDN on the datasource:

> Typically this property will be set for an entire column of cells
>   through the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource property.
>
> If possible, set DataSource to a source containing only the possible
>   selections, like a column of selections. Then the DisplayMember
>   property doesn't need to be set. But if the source is more
>   complicated, set DisplayMember to the name of the property or column
>   from which to retrieve possible selections.
>
> If DataSource is set to a string array, then ValueMember and
>   DisplayMember do not need to be set because each string in the array
>   will be used for both value and display.

So in your case, you will need to do something similar to the following:

```
Dim cListItems As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of MyListItem)

cListItems.Add(New MyListItem("Text to be displayed", "value of the item"))

Dim dgvcbc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(0), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
dgvcbc.DataSource = cListItems
dgvcbc.DisplayMember = "Text"
dgvcbc.ValueMember = "Value"
```

Finally, if the values are the same for all cells, then you will probably want to assign the datasource to the column when you create it. All of the above code will remain the same, except you will replace the `dgvcbc` reference with the variable that holds the `datagridviewcomboboxcolumn`.

Comment: yes, but you can give me an example how i can assign and get values to each items of ant combobox?, Thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with additional info and a suggested method for resolving the problem.

Comment: well I see that assigns the value correctly, but I have another question but before closing the question, as I can show the value of ITEM to be changed comobobox?, Thanks again and sorry for the inconvenience